# Faster methods from txt to ArrayList in Android

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm inserting lines from a .txt file into an ArrayList using a Scanner method below. The problem is that this is taking around 20-25 seconds to accomplish because of the large number of lines. Are there other faster methods to go from txt to ArrayList?

```
public void openFile (){
    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.wordsen);
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
    Scanner is = new Scanner (in);
    while (is.hasNextLine()){
        names.add(is.nextLine());
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is 'large' number of files? Are you reading files of 1MB or 1GB etc?

Comment: It's one text file with all the English words. http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt

Comment: Use a BufferedReader instead of a Scanner and try to size the ArrayList beforehand if you can (if the number of lines is known).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("profile.txt");
    if(file.exists()){
        try {
             FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);
             BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
         while(true){
                          String t1=br.readLine();
        //here add your read text to map or hash table adapter  
                    }

                    }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
                     catch (IOException e) {
        }
   //and on completion ad the list to arraylist
```

Comment: `while(true)` => no need to throw an exception here. You should check if you have reached the end of the file instead.